# How to emit events from celery task

Tags: python, flask, celery, flask-socketio

Basically, I am trying to generate events on a server side in a separate thread. I have a `celery.task` that should emit events, but its code is never executed.

```
import json
import time

from celery import Celery

from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import render_template
from flask import request

from flask_socketio import SocketIO

broker_url = "redis://localhost:6379/1"

celery = Celery(broker=broker_url)
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue=broker_url)


@celery.task
def countdown(n):
    print("countdown", n)
    for i in range(n+1):
        time.sleep(1)
        socketio.emit(
            "countdown",
            {"remaining": n - i},
            namespace="/test/"
        )


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/start_countdown/", methods=["POST"])
def start_countdown():
    data = json.loads(request.data.decode())
    countdown.delay([int(data["time"])])
    return jsonify(time_to_wait=data["time"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(debug=True)
```

Views are responding fine, but task is silent and I can't understand, why?

**UPD**

I had rearranged my code like [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat). Folder structure is completely same, and files are same too. In `app/main` folder I have extra `tasks.py` file.

```
import time

from celery import Celery
from flask_socketio import emit

from app import socketio
from config import broker_url


celery = Celery(broker=broker_url)

@celery.task
def countdown(n):
    print(n)

    for i in range(n+1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Socket", socketio)
        print("Server", socketio.server)
        socketio.emit(
            "countdown",
            {"remaining": n - i},
            namespace="/test/"
        )
```

I start celery worker with `celery -A app.main.tasks worker` command. And when code of the `countdown` task is executed, it fails with this exception:

```
[2017-10-12 19:04:07,797: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 13
[2017-10-12 19:04:08,799: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] <flask_socketio.SocketIO object at 0x7f07d2a0fc50>
[2017-10-12 19:04:08,803: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task app.main.tasks.countdown[68ae2e43-6ab7-4d52-8b3a-a9aaff46c489] raised unexpected: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'emit'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/tasks.py", line 24, in countdown
    namespace="/test/"
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 357, in emit
    self.server.emit(event, *args, namespace=namespace, room=room,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'emit'
```

`socketio.server` inside my task is `None` for some reason, while in `app/main/events.py` file it is appropriate object. Looks like in my task `socketio` object is not completely initialized, probably, because in celery process execution flow is different, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: How are you connecting to this application from the client?

Comment: @Miguel, here is index.html and magic.js https://gist.github.com/montreal91/8a9ba9033df1469ccd51e1c2e7a3ac9f. I can add them to the post, if required. `start_countdown` is called, but the background task does not start.

Comment: Are running at least one Celery worker process in addition to your main server?

Comment: Right now, yes.

Comment: Is the task running at all then? You can add logging to the Celery worker to see if it launches the task.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You said you are running a Celery worker. I asked you to run it with logging, to see if it is executing the tasks that your main process is sending to it. Have you done that?

Comment: @Miguel, I have updated my question, hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Is your celery task in a separate tasks.py module? eg:

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('tasks', broker=broker_url)
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue=broker_url)

@celery.task
def countdown(n):
    print("countdown", n)
    for i in range(n+1):
        time.sleep(1)
        socketio.emit(
            "countdown",
            {"remaining": n - i},
            namespace="/test/"
        )
```

Then you can start this worker on the prompt:

```
 celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

you should then run your main code and add:

```
 from tasks import countdown
```

and call your countdown function which will run in a separate process

Answer (score 0):

I could only get this to work with Redis as a broker, wasted hours trying with RabbitMQ as the broker and couldn't emit messages from within a celery task. Make sure you create a new instance using the Flask SocketIO constructor apart from the main flask app's socketio instance.

Comment: I've redesigned my whole system and current version does not use celery or RabbitMQ at all. And I started to doubt if those are useful tools for for communicating between *python* processes. I would rather use RabbitMQ to make two programs written with two different languages talk to each other.

Comment: If you drop RabbitMQ , at least initially just to get it working then its very straight forward just with Redis + Celery + SocketIO.

Comment: I'm having same issue now and creating a new instance with the flask socketio constructor don't solve it. From the logs I see that I am able to send messages I attached to the celery task_success event but the client just don't receive it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when working with Flask-SocketIO and Celery.

As others have mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33763838/9283274) we could not communicate with the client from the Celery task because they are two different processes.

My solution is was to create an endpoint on the Flask server that basically broadcasts events to the client. This endpoint would take json data that looks like this:

```json
{
    "event_name": "Event name",
    "room": "roomId", // optional field 
    "data": "<data you want to send>" // this is the data you want to send to the users
   "broadcast_secret": <secret> // This would ensure ensure that we the endpoint is not public to everyone. If this secret is invalid then we would not broadcast anything to the client.
}
```

Here is how the endpoint looks like:

```py
@app.route('/braodcast',methods = ['POST'])
def broadcast_to_client(self):
    json_data = self.get_json()
    event_name = json_data.get('event_name')
    room = json_data.get('room')
    data = json_data.get('data')
    broadcast_secret = json_data.get('broadcast_secret')
    status_code, emitted = 400,  False
    if event_name and broadcast_secret == os.getenv('BROADCAST_SECRET'):
        socketio.emit(event_name, data, room=room)
        status_code, emitted = 200, True

    return {'emitted': emitted}, status_code
```

I then created a helper function that makes a post request to this endpoint from my celery task using the requests module:

```py
import requests

def send_socket_event_from_celery(event_name, data=None, room=None):
    app_host = os.getenv('APP_HOST')
    broadcast_path = f'{app_host}/broadcast'

    json_data = {
        'event_name': event_name,
        'data': data,
        'room': room,
        'broadcast_secret': os.getenv('BROADCAST_SECRET')
    }

    requests.post(broadcast_path, json=json_data)
```

Now in any celery task, I need to emit an event in socket IO I simply call this method.

```py
send_socket_event_from_celery('sample-event', data, room=some_room)
```