# Flask-SocketIO and Celery task, socketio.emit() not emitting to client after task

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, celery, flask-socketio

I have trouble when trying to `emit()` to all connected clients with flask-socketio after successfully executing a celery task.

The idea is the following:

Call flask endpoint -> triggers celery task on worker

```
# api.py
@app.route('/api/task', method=['GET'])
def trigger_celery_task():
     celery_task.delay()
```

Before finishing the task, the celery worker calls another flask api endpoint which triggers the socket server to emit an event

```
# tasks.py
from server.app import create_celery_app # see below
celery = create_celery_app()

@celery.task
def celery_task():
     # exec some long task
     import requests
     url='http://backend:5000/api/update_data'
     requests.get(url)
     return None

# api.py
@app.route('/api/update_data', method=['GET'])
def trigger_update():
     from server.app import socketio
     socketio.emit('new_data_available', {'message': 'update'})
```

My flask application gives me the following error message (when 2 clients are connected):

```
"GET /api/update_data HTTP/1.1" 200
Cannot send to sid 85d...
Cannot send to sid 52c...
```

However, if I manually call the endpoint `/api/update_data` the socket server emits the event correctly and all clients receive it:

```
85d...: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["new_data_available",{"message":"update"}]
52c...: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["new_data_available",{"message":"update"}]
"GET /api/update_data HTTP/1.1" 200
```

My configuration is as follows:

```
# app.py

# initialize sql-alchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

# initialize socketIO server
socketio = SocketIO(path='/api/socket-io', engineio_logger=True)

def create_app(config_name):
    # initialize flask app
    app = FlaskAPI(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    # configuration
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    CORS(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    socketio.init_app(app)

    # add blueprints/routes
    # ...

    return app

def create_celery_app(app=None):
    config_name = os.getenv('APP_SETTINGS')
    app = app or create_app(config_name)

    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

And finally the run config:

```
# run.py
import os
from server.app import create_app

config_name = os.getenv('APP_SETTINGS')  # config_name = "development"
app = create_app(config_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threaded=True)
    from server.app import socketio
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Note that I'm running the complete application in docker containers which are orchestrated by docker-compose, just in case it matters.

Thank you very much, I appreciate any help.

Comment: The problem here might be that your flask server is the one which has socket connection with the client and not your celery process.
you might refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33763838/4662041
You can also refer to this section of the documentation of Flask-SocketIO: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#emitting-from-an-external-process

Comment: it certainly should be like this, but as I'm calling the endpoint of the flask server (HTTP GET in the same way as I am calling it manually!?) the `socketio.emit()` should be called in the flask server context, correct? I've tried the approach with a redis queue which is outlined there, it didn't work for me yet.